# Vimeo embed player not working on express proxy middleware

Tags: docker, express, vimeo, http-proxy, vimeo-api

I have the embed links for vimeoplayer i want to use my express server as proxy. I have added the endpoint which bascially proxies to vimeo embed link. My code is working fine on my local machine but on server sometimes it redirects to vimeo home page(vimeo.com).I am using http-proxy-middleware npm package and have done docker deployment using kubernetes on server. kindly let me know what steps can i take to stop it from redirecting and my proxy behave as it is intended to behave

Code is attached

`` app.use(`/test-vimeo`, proxy({target: `https://player.vimeo.com/video/709386126?h=21417feddb`,changeOrigin: true})) ``

Comment: Can you please share version of http-proxy-middleware which you are using?

Comment: http-proxy-middleware version is 2.0.0